# How can we upload a file to a chrome extension?

Tags: file, google-chrome-extension, upload, transfer

I am trying to make an extension to transfer files. But I cannot find the api to transfer file. I found some api(fileSystem) but it only works with chrome apps, it does not work with extension. I am working on Google Chrome Extension.

Comment: Read the file contents, there are lots of examples, then you can use it. The question is too broad and non-specific so there's nothing else I can add.

Comment: I am trying to upload a pdf file and send it to a database using the extension. @wOxxOm

Comment: Like I said, the question is too broad so the only answer is there are [lots of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+upload+file+to+server).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I figured it out. @wOxxOm